# How to authenticate with Sentinel by username?

Tags: php, authentication, sentinel

I'm using Sentinel by Cartalyst for authentication with PHP. The traditional way to authenticate is by use of e-mail and password, as we can read in their documentation:

```
$credentials = [
    'email'    => 'john.doe@example.com',
    'password' => 'password',
];

Sentinel::authenticate($credentials);
```

The default *users* table provided by the library is like that:

```
id | email | password | permissions |last_login | first_name | created_at | updated_at
```

I want to add a *username* column and authenticate using Sentinel by *username* and *password*. Is it possible?

Answer (score 10):

You can modify this example here

http://naomiaro.com/2015/07/08/multiple-login-attributes-with-sentinel-and-laravel/

In your Users model you must override the attribute $loginNames, and add username to the attribute $fillable.

```
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser as SentinelUser;

class User extends SentinelUser {

    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'username',
        'password',
        'last_name',
        'first_name',
        'permissions',
    ];

    protected $loginNames = ['username'];

}

Sentinel::authenticate([
    'username'    => 'fake',
    'password' => 'password'
]);
```